# How to make a login flow IOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, authentication, storyboard

I made a login trough the facebook in my app using the Facebook SDK. Basically I have a login screen that when the user clicks in "Facebook" button it make whole auth routine (open the safari and ask for accept the permission). When the user is not logged after accept the access to app it goes to another view (Main screen of app).

The problem is when the user is already logged... I would like open the app in main screen without display login view.

I'm verifying if user is logger in LoginController at viewDidAppear and calling **performSegueWithIdentifier** method because in **viewDidLoad** it doesn't work.

Which is the best way to make a login screen?

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController{

    let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        print("Will Appear method")

        if (self.defaults.stringForKey("isLogged") != nil){
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("facebookLoginSegue", sender: nil)
        }

    }

    //MARK - Actions
    @IBAction func facebookLogin(sender: UIButton) {

        FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], fromViewController:self, handler: { (result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email")){
                    self.defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "isLogged")
                    self.getFBUserData()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    print(result)
                }
            })
        }
    }

}
```

I thought about verify the user "session" in AppDelegate and change the rootViewController of storyboard. Is it a good practice or a crazy idea?

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think you need to put this in `viewDidAppear:`

Comment: Make your Initial view to be main view and preform a `if ` statement segue when use is logged out in **viewDidLoad:** , that way they stay in main view when they're logged in .

Comment: Hi @FarhadNezhad, I found a way... thanks for your help.
in AppDelegate I validate if user is not logged I change my RootView.

Comment: @AlessandroGarcez Yes, that another way to do it, Im glad I could help a little, if I did :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way:

First set the main screen as root view in storyboard

[image]

Second step is verify if the user is logged in AppDelegate.
If the user is not logged show change root view controller to login view.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        if (self.defaults.stringForKey("isLogged") == nil){
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") 
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    }
```

And finishing, add a segue from login view to Main view with specific identifier... and when the user successfully login call **self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueIdentifier", sender: nil)**

```
if (self.defaults.stringForKey("isLogged") != nil){
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("facebookLoginSegue", sender: nil)
        }
```

Comment: Vague solution with no coherent explanation.